# Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005):

Tags: c#, condor

I did c# code that opens ms word and it runs correct. I want to run this program in condor environment and i got an error, says..

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.
   at Console_try.Program.open_document(String pwd, String file_name)
   at Console_try.Program.Generate_small(String pwd, Int32 pos, Int32 siz, String file_name)
   at Console_try.Program.Generate_small(String pwd, Int32 pos, Int32 siz, String file_name)
   at Console_try.Program.Generate_small(String pwd, Int32 pos, Int32 siz, String file_name)
   at Console_try.Program.Main(String[] args).
```

I think this error belongs to MS visual studio c#.

Comment: Please add the project references, how the office dll's are included into the tested application and explain that a condor environment is. Are you sure word is installed?

Comment: The error code (0x80080005) "belongs" to windows and occurs because it fails to open or communicate with ms word. I don't think you should be trying that on a distributed computing platform - as CodingBarfield mentioned, ms word may not be installed on one of the computers, different versions may be installed, security settings may prevent you from starting it, it may not start in a timely fashion, and all these issues may return this error.

Comment: That's CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE, COM couldn't get the Office program you are using started.  That's clearly an environmental problem, surely related to "condor environment", whatever it is.